# How to create a curvy bend in a rectangle using the node tool?

Tags: inkscape, svg, shapes

I created a simple rectangle , then i changes it from from a shape to `object to path`. At this point it has four nodes. I proceed to add 6 more like below:

[image]

What i was trying to achieve is a slight bend in the middle , something like a saucer lets say but even more subtle (I.E. a very tiny bend). unfortunately the bend seems very forced and unnatural and also pointy. My question is how do i create a smooth bend ?

I.E. i don't want the bend in the middle to be pointy but more curvy. how do i go about doing this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the Edit Paths by Nodes tool <kbd>N</kbd> to grab a path and bend it. There's no need to add any extra nodes to the rectangle for this to work.

Example

[image]

What this really does is pulls out Bézier curves from the nodes.

When you have the rectangle selected using the Nodes tool <kbd>N</kbd>, click and drag a rectangle selection around all four nodes, this will select all the nodes and you will be able to see the Bézier curve handles, which you can then adjust manually.

[image]

Many kinds of slight curves are possible depending on how you position the Bézier curve handles

[image]

Another method is to add extra nodes and turn those into symmetric curve nodes, which can then be adjusted manually in a similar way.

[image]

Comment: Thank you .. very effective !

Comment: just a supplementary question , what if i want to move the edges up and down as well ? the same trick does't seem to work. any straightforward approach :)

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik - then just click once to select an object, and move the scale handles. It's one click to see the scale handles, and two clicks for rotate and skew. [see example here](https://imgur.com/1lxwO4b)

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik - or select and move nodes. [see example here](https://imgur.com/RwLI6Vb)

Comment: its the 2nd one i wanted. Thanks a ton !! :D

Answer (score 2):

You can use "Bend" path effect as follows:

- Select your path.
- **Path** > **Path Effects...** and add `Bend` effect.
- Select Edit on-canvas and use the mouse to bend the path.

[image: bend a path]

Comment: Thanks for the shortcut will try this !